# How to create a hashing function which buckets an array of integers into random buckets?

Tags: algorithm, math, hash, integer, modulo

So I am doing something part theoretical and part practical, trying to find the balance of what is realistic. Currently I am thinking about a situation where we have 3 properties which specify a table for a record:

1. `org_id`: organization grouping (int possible values == `2147483647` on postgres ~~ 2 billion)
2. `type_id`: basic category of the record (int possible values)
3. `chunk_id`: chunking of records into "int" chunks (~2 billion records per chunk)

The `chunk_id` would be a static/permanent value, but it maps to a dynamic "shard" url. Basically, the shard is the database instance which will house all records of a specific chunk, for a specific type and org. So given an org and type, if we are given a chunk, we know all those records in that chunk will be in a specific shard.

So you'd have a table, the `shard_lookup` table, which maps a (`org_id`, `type_id`, `chunk_id`) to a shard url/address. Pretty basic.

Anyways, the problem would arise if there were billions of orgs and billions of shards. There would be too many pieces of info to store in memory I think, too many records in the `shard_lookup` table to fit on one machine/instance. So you would have to subdivide the `shard_lookup` table into small chunks too! You would have to shard the shard lookup table :)

Well we can do something simpler for this case, since we have a hard limit on how many records we are allowing in the system, for now at least (another story). We can theoretically take the (`org_id`, `type_id`, `chunk_id`) tuple, and hash it to get an index, and then from that index we would be able to know what "shard lookup shard" to go to, which would contain the `shard_lookup` table that we know contains our tuple, and then we could look in that table to find the specific type table address. So `hash -> shard lookup shard -> record shard`.

So that's the back of the story. Question is, how can I take this tuple of 3 integers, and hash it to produce a random bucket? It's probably something simple, but I'm not seeing it. By random bucket, I mean each tuple always resolves to the same bucket, but the distribution is seemingly randomized.

Basically what is going in my head is something with `modulo` but I can't pinpoint what the solution would be yet. It seems something like:

```
if (org_id % 3 === 0 && type_id % 3 === 0 && chunk_id % 3 === 0) {
  return 3 // third bucket
} else if (org_id % 2 === 0 && type_id % 2 === 0 && chunk_id % 2 === 0) {
  return 2 // second bucket
} else {
  return 1 // first bucket
}
```

But really you'd want to test way more combinations than that, or else everything would fall in the 1 bucket pretty much. So how would you do this sort of thing in a dynamic sort of way?

Say we can tune the algorithm to having n possible buckets as well, so initially we start with just one bucket (everything is in one place), but later it is 2 buckets, then 3, etc.

Comment: Something like `(org_id * 17 + type_id * 31 + chunk_id * 5) % num_buckets`?

Comment: How did you get that? What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Just a few prime factors? Does it give what you want?